# Powershell Invoke-sqlcmd keeping connection open and trying to reuse it

Tags: powershell, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a Powershell script that uses `invoke-sqlcmd` to apply scripts to a series of development databases. I loop through a list of scripts and compare it to the current release level of the database and then apply the required scripts to get the DB to the release level it needs to be at.  Certain databases are reference databases and are in a READ_ONLY state. I connect to those database run an alter DB script setting them to READ_WRITE apply the script then change the back to READ_ONLY. Overall the script works well, the issue is it looks like when PowerShell first opens a connection to the database and applies the first script and then goes to alter the DB back to READ_ONLY the database has objects locked.  I've traced it back to the previous connection and a Shared_Transaction_Workspace lock (sys.dm_tran_locks) for what looks to be the previous powershell connection.  Why is this connection still open after the `invoke-sqlcmd` has completed and is there anything I can do about it? Can I force `invoke-sqlcmd` to use a new connection for each invocation of the cmdlet?

I have tried a messy fix killing the offending connection and then retrying the connection but I think there is something better.

Comment: I think this is a known bug for 2008 (fixed in 2012): http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/482833/invoke-sqlcmd-doesnt-release-database-connection    See also: http://poshcode.org/2665

Comment: Thanks that's it.  I'll try the work around on the connect item.

Answer (score 10):

I've always done this and it seems to work:

```
[System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection]::ClearAllPools()
```

Comment: I had trouble with a PS script I've used for a while after I introduced a SQL Script that would drop and recreate the datase and/or set single/multi user mode on the database. Thus causing the reused connection for invoke-sqlcmd to fail. ClearAllPools() after that script fixed my issue where calling the next sql script would crash the PS script. Thank you.

Comment: I had trouble using `Invoke-Sqlcmd` inside a `foreach`. First iteration managed to execute the script but the second and the rest never executed. I added `[System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection]::ClearAllPools()` just after `Invoke-Sqlcmd` command and it worked like a charm. Thank you.

Comment: Use `[Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection]::ClearAllPools()` for newer versions of Invoke-Sqlcmd. 11 years later this is still an issue.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I know that this is a very old post and the people from Microsoft told that fixed this issue (as told the article mentioned by David Brabant) but maybe I'm not the luckiest guy and have to make an workaround to make it happens.

Even running Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP1) - 11.0.3128.0 (X64) I had the same issue and after make some researches I got a way to get some parameter from Invoke-Sqlcmd as output so I can get the Session ID of the current user process with the built-in @@SPID global variable from the SQL Server and make a connection with ADO.NET to execute a KILL clause to close the opened connection.

## So let's to the workaround applied in my case

```
#Invoke the Invoke-Sqlcmd to execute an script from a file
Invoke-Sqlcmd -Server "[SERVER_NAME]" -Database [DATABASE_NAME] -Username [USER] -Password [PASSWORD] -InputFile [DOT_SQL_FILE_PATH]
#Invoke the Invoke-Sqlcmd to execute a inline SQL statement to get the SessionID as a Powershell variable
$SQLSession = Invoke-Sqlcmd -Server "[SERVER_NAME]" -Database [DATABASE_NAME] -Username [USER] -Password [PASSWORD] -query "select @@spid as SessionID"
# Build query to execute KILL clause
$DbQuery = "KILL " + $SQLSession.SessionID;

# Create SQL connection with ADO.NET
$DbConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$DbConnectionString = "Server = [SERVER_NAME]; Database = [DATABASE_NAME]; User ID=[USER]; Password=[PASSWORD];"
$DbConnection.ConnectionString = $DbConnectionString
$DbConnection.Open()

# Create SQL command for KILL clause
$DbCommand = New-Object System.Data.SQLClient.SQLCommand  
$DbCommand.Connection = $DbConnection 
$DbCommand.CommandText = $DbQuery 

# Execute KILL clause
$DbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

# Close connection
$DbConnection.Close()
```

I hope that it helps

Answer (score 0):

Even though I am using the newest version of SSMS (Version 16.5.3 - Build 13.0.16106.4), I still get this issue.  I haven't figured out what the "right" way of forcing the connection closed is, but I have a work-around that is simple and resolves the issue for me.  If you just need to get the connection off the database, you can do the following:

1. Run normal command(s)

   ```
   Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance "SOME_SERVER" -Database "SOME_DB" ...
   ```
2. When you are ready to eliminate the connection from the database:

   ```
   Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance "SOME_SERVER" -Database "SOME_DB" -Query "use [master];"
   ```

This will switch the connection to master, thus removing it from the database of interest.  If you absolutely need the connection closed, I think you need to resort to SqlClient or such.